# How do I setup binding so that selected value of combobox in one control changes control template of a different control?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I have something like this...
The first user control is as below

```
<UserControl x:Class="FirstControl">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="PrintTemplates>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="PrintTemplateA">
               .....
            </ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="PrintTemplateB">
               .....
            </ControlTemplate>
        <ResourceDictionary/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="PrintTemplateComboBox" 
                  ItemsSource="{StaticResource PrintTemplates}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The second user control is as below... please see where I have the uppercase comments in code. I want to set the control template of PrintBox to whatever the user chooses in the combobox in the FirstControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="SecondControl">
    <Grid>
        <local:PrintBox x:Name="PrintBox"
                        Template={Binding SelectedValue, Source= I WANT THIS TO BE PrintTemplateComboBox IN THE FirstControl />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: have you tried ElemenetName="PrintTemplateComboBox" Path=SelectedValue  
?

Comment: Thank you but that wont work in my case since these controls are not on the same window/control

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Grid>
        <local:PrintBox x:Name="PrintBox"
                       Template="{Binding ElementName=PrintTemplateComboBox,Path=SelectedValue}"/>
  </Grid>
```

or you can use a converter to be certain what you return back

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Local:YourTemplateConverter x:Key="yourTemplateConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
Template="{Binding ElementName=PrintTemplateComboBox,Path=SelectedValue,Converter={StaticResource yourTemplateConverter}}"
</Grid
```

and this is the converter

```
class YourTemplateConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
       //value is whwat YourTemplateConverter get from the other combobox
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but that wont work in my case since these controls are not on the same window/control

Comment: So in this case you need a controller that will know both controls. And than you can register to selection change event of one control to another and from there to set a binded property in the viewmodel